# How to separate the last part of the string in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to separate the last part of the string that comes after the last "/" symbol.

For example:

```
http://superuser.com/questions/ask                                  -> ask
http://techonthenet.com/excel/howto/14385                           -> 14385
http://www.likeoffice.com/28057/excel-text-mid/en/answers/howto     -> howto
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)))
```

Comment: In two days you should be able to mark your answer as correct so it is effectively "complete".